# Bioshock; walking problem?

Tags: technical-issues, bioshock

In Bioshock when I walk forward and let go of the forward key he keeps on walking, but eventually stops after a couple seconds. Would like to know if I could possibly fix it, or if it's just my computer/keyboard. Anyone else having the same problem? I'm playing Bioshock off of Steam on Windows 8. Other than that the game runs perfectly fine with no lagging at all.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: As an answer said, the movement can be a bit clunky, but not that bad.....you might want to consider cleaning your keyboard out, or at least the WASD keys. (Pull them off and clean near the switches)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way Bioshock was made.

It's the same in Bioshock 2 as well

Bioshock controls have always been clunky, especially when it comes to movement.

I've played on both Xbox 360 & PC version and both have the exact same movement delay.

So it's not something we can fix, maybe it's just a bug that they couldn't fix or maybe it is used to give the game more 'effect'

but to answer your question there is nothing we as the players can do to fix it :(

Comment: I realise it's been some time, but still curious: why the downvote??

Comment: @BMWurm I'm as confused as you are